# single quote JS encodeuri vs PHP rawurlencode

Tags: php, rawurl

I'm trying to imitate a POST request made by AJAX in PHP with cURL.

One thing I noticed, why does PHP escapes the single quote as `%27` while JS's encodeuricomponent leaves it like it is?

Is there really a function in PHP that's actually THE SAME as the JS one?

Comment: Why not just build an array and use `http_build_query()`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to find a PHP function that doesn't encode the single quote. Reason being is PHP adhere's more strictly to [RFC 3986](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986.html) which includes the single quote.

`RFC 3986` reserves special characters such as `!, ', (, ), and *`.

> URIs include components and subcomponents that are delimited by
>   characters in the "reserved" set.  These characters are called
>   "reserved" because they may (or may not) be defined as delimiters by
>   the generic syntax, by each scheme-specific syntax, or by the
>   implementation-specific syntax of a URI's dereferencing algorithm.
>   If data for a URI component would conflict with a reserved
>   character's purpose as a delimiter, then the conflicting data must be 
>   percent-encoded before the URI is formed.
>
> reserved    = gen-delims / sub-delims
>
> gen-delims  = ":" / "/" / "?" / "#" / "[" / "]" / "@"
>
> sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
>                     / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="

If you want to match php and have the single quote encoded in js you can use a function like this.

```
function fixedEncodeURIComponent (str) {  
  return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, escape);  
}
```

Why do you need to not encode it? It should still work with a CURL.